# inserting records from database in multiple xml files in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml, mysqli

I am trying to put database records in multiple xml files,but i m not able to do that.basically i have 200 rows in db table,i have to put them in 4 different xml files with 50 each.Like when ever it crosses 50 rows,should automatically make a new xml file.
But i m not able to develop the for loop logic.

```
<?php

//Create Database connection
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'dbname');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
}
$query = 'select * from tablename';

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

//Create SimpleXMLElement object
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

//Add each column value a node of the XML object
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $counter = 0;
    if (count($row) % 50) {
        $mydata = $xml->addChild('mydata');


        $mydata->Id = $row['PID'];
        $fp         = fopen("sitemap$counter.xml", "wb");

        //Write the XML nodes
        fwrite($fp, $xml->asXML());
        $xml = new XML();
    } else {
        $counter++;
    }
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);
//Create the XML file
//Close the database connection
fclose($fp);
```

Now there are 200 rows in db table,i want to make 4 different xml files with 50 rows each.

I m not able to do that .Please help

Comment: put your `fwrite` stuff inside the loop and keep track of how many records you've loaded. when you hit 50, you dump the xml to a file, then start a new file and reset the counter to 0.

Comment: inside loop means in while loop?I will just update my code what i got.Please check whether its correct or not?

Comment: do you have any other loops that you didn't show in your code?

Comment: no i dnt have any other loops.I just updated my code with what u said.Please check whether its correct or not .If not please help then

Comment: you need to reset your $xml object every time you dump it to a file, otherwise you'll just dump 50 records, then 100 records, etc... plus, you're using the SAME filename each time, so you're just going to be deleting your previously dumped records. In other words, you haven't accomplished much except writing the file multiple times now instead of just once.

Comment: i made the file name dynamic now,that one i missed last time.I didnt get resetting the xml object.How to do that

Comment: just do another `$xml = new XML()`-type thing after you finish writing to the file.

Comment: Please check the entire code now and check for any flaw sir for functionality

Comment: sir.is the code currently fine now?

Comment: That's up to you to decide. We are not here to do your job for you...

Comment: thats right.but I am just asking you to help me in correcting the code as i m not that experienced in php

Answer (score 0):

What you've got is a **Traversable** that you want to cut into chunks of 50 Iterations each.

For the brevity in my answer, I'll change this to four result rows and I'd like to have two iterations each, so to say, create two files with two entries.

You can do this easily by writing a little function that is chunking an **Iterator** with the help of a **Generator**:

```
/**
 * @param Iterator $iterator
 * @param int      $size
 *
 * @return Generator
 */
function ChunkGenerator(Iterator $iterator, $size) {
    $size = max(0, (int) $size);
    while ($size-- && $iterator->valid()) {
        yield $iterator->key() => $iterator->current();
        $size && $iterator->next();
    }
}
```

This little function returns a **Traversale** again in form of a **Generator** that will iterate over `$size` iterations from `$iterator`.

As your `$result` is a **Traversable** but not an **Iterator**, you need to wrap it inside an **IteratorIterator** first. Then you can iterate over it and then inside that iteration over the chunk. See the example:

```
$iterator = new IteratorIterator($result);

foreach ($iterator as $void) {
    echo "new chunk:\n";
    foreach (ChunkGenerator($iterator, 2) as $row) {
        echo $row['PID'], "\n";
    }
}
```

My exemplary output by starting with a PID of 1000 then gives:

```
new chunk:
1000
1001
new chunk:
1002
1003
```

As you can see with the stacked `foreach`, the inner loop provides the rows per each file. the outer loop represents the files. It's now easy to put the XML output logic into such a loop:

```
foreach ($iterator as $void) {

    //Create SimpleXMLElement object
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

    foreach (ChunkGenerator($iterator, 2) as $row) {
        $xml->addChild('row')->Id = $row['PID'];
    }

    // output the file
    $xml->saveXML('php://output'); // place your filename here
}
```

The output (I use exemplary stdout as "filename", you can just put your filenames in there) then is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml><row><Id>1000</Id></row><row><Id>1001</Id></row></xml>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml><row><Id>1002</Id></row><row><Id>1003</Id></row></xml>
```

Albeit the example is a little complex (you've got two loops inside each other), it still represents well the modelling you've got: files and then rows per file.

You can also play with the online demo: https://eval.in/173066